# Pointers to member functions - can't understand g++ error message

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I am writing a reporting system, including a class - Datum - with various data points and a class - Statistic - with metadata about the report lines. The metadata includes pointers to Datum member functions to get and set the data.

```
class Statistic
{
    .
    .
    .
        double (Datum::*getter) () const;
        void (Datum::*setter) (const double);
    .
    .
    .
}
```

I have written a constructor for Statistic:

```
Statistic::Statistic (
        double Datum::*a_getter (),
        void (Datum::*a_setter)(const double))
{
    getter  = a_getter;
    setter  = a_setter;
}
```

This doesn't compile; g++ outputs the error

> cannot convert 'double Datum::* ( * )()' to 'double (Datum::*)() const' in assignment

[Note: There are no spaces between the second asterisk and the brackets, but if I leave them out the asterisk is not shown after formatting]

at the line that assigns to m_getter.

I'm poor at interpreting pointers to functions and I can't work out what I've actually written.
I seem to have declared m_getter to be a pointer to a Datum member function taking no arguments and returning a double. I'm not sure what the `const` has ended up referring to. This is approximately what I want - I'd like to be a const pointer to a const Datum member function taking no arguments and returning a double. (I appreciate that means I'll need to initialise it in the constructor rather than assigning to it.)
I cannot make out what I've ended up saying `getter` is, g++ is emitting more `*`s than I can cope with.

How should I declare m_getter and my constructor?

Comment: `double Datum::*getter ()` isn't `double (Datum::*getter) (),`

Comment: You have member variables called "getter"  and "setter", whose names you shadow in the constructor, and you assign to "m_getter" and "m_setter". Please post real code.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: If I were you, I would use a typedef for your pointer to function. That way, you wouldn't confuse pointer to function to pointer to member.

Comment: @molbdnilo Sorry, you are quite right this is slightly bowdlerised to make a minimal example. The member variables should be prefixed. I will edit the question.

Comment: @eerorika. Sorry I have made one too many edit to minimise my example. I've modified the variable names throughout to reflect what I hae rather than what I'm aiming at.

Comment: @xryl669. Whenever I look for information about pointers to member functions, I see advice to use `typedef`s. I appreciate that they will make it easier to use once written, but I think that , at least for me, the extra layer will make it harder to write the code in the first place.

Comment: @nurdglaw You're right, since writing the typedef implies understanding the concepts explained below. Yet, for the users of your code dealing with `PtrToMethodT` is easier than `Ret (A::*variable)(Arg)` in terms of readability.

Comment: @nurdglaw Problem isn't so much with minimality, but with completeness of the example.

Answer (score 2):

`double Datum::*getter ()` declares `getter` as a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer-to-member-of-`Datum` that points to a `double` - a `double Datum::*`.

Use the same syntax as in your member declaration; `double (Datum::*getter) ()`.

Or even better: use a type alias.

```
class Statistc
{
    using getter_function = double (Datum::*)() const;
    using setter_function = void (Datum::*)(double);

    getter_function m_getter;
    setter_function m_setter;

    // ...
};
Statistic::Statistic (
        getter_function getter,
        setter_function setter)
    : m_getter(getter),
      m_setter(setter)
{
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I'm not sure whether I would have found it so easy to follow @KamilCuk's answer without this one.

Answer (score 1):

From the top, with extra spaces:

```
double * somepointer;
         ^^^^^^^^^^^ a pointer to double
double Datum::* otherpointer;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^ a pointer to double within `Datum`
                             The double that we point to is within Datum
double Datum::*   getter();  
                  ^^^^^^ - a declaration of a function named `getter`
                           that returns a pointer to double within `Datum`
                           and takes no arguments
double (Datum::*   getter2)();
                   ^^^^^^^ - a function pointer to member function
                             can point to a function within `Datum`
                             can be called using an instance of `Datum`
                             that returns double and takes no arguments
double (Datum::*   getter3)() const;
                   ^^^^^^^ - a function pointer to member function
                             can point to a function within `Datum`
                             can be called using an instance of `const Datum`
                             that returns double and takes no arguments
```

You can:

```
class Statistic
{
    double (Datum::*m_getter) () const;
    void (Datum::*m_setter) (const double);

    Statistic::Statistic (
            double (Datum::*getter)() const,
            void (Datum::*setter)(const double))
    {
        m_getter  = getter;
        m_setter  = setter;
    }
};
```

Comment: Many thanks; I consider this a full answer as it tells me how to interpret various forms of variable and function definition, and how to achieve my objective.